# I am using laravel sharing using jorenvanhocht/laravel-share package but it does not show preview or thumbnail when I share on Social websites

Tags: laravel, sharing

I am using jorenvanhocht/laravel-share package in laravel.Its working fine but when I share it on social site then it does not show preview or thumbnail.Please let me know how can it be done.

```
echo Share::currentPage($video->title)
        ->facebook()
        ->twitter()
        ->linkedin('Extra linkedin summary can be passed here')
        ->whatsapp();

<input type="text" value="{{ url()->full() }}" readonly>
```

The above code is working fine when I share link but the problem is only it does not show preview or thumbnail of the video but just only link.
So, I want the preview with the link.

Answer (score -1):

You mean a preview on facebook? Those aren't created by adding information to your link, but Facebooks creates them when a bot visits your site and sees certain meta tags.

Most sites use the OpenGraph standard, you can read more about it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/ or https://ogp.me/#metadata. If you use the right tags, previews, and names will automatically be added to previews on different social media platforms.

Comment: I did it too.But when I put any static image then it works but when I put the links to dynamic content then it won't.

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content="{{ $video->thumbnail_url }}">
      <meta property="og:description" content="{{ $video->description }}">
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://test.addviu.com/">
      <meta property="og:title" content="{{ $video->title }}">
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="{{ $video->thumbnail_url }}">
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="og:image:width" content="720" />
      <meta property="og:image:height" content="720" />

Comment: It can take a while for Facebook to index pages. Check back in a few minutes, and if the content still isn't loaded then something is wrong. But it all looks good, so unless the URLs are invalid (maybe they don't include the URL, but just the path?) I think it should work.

Comment: its been more than an hour.the URLs are fine as its working fine in the same page.Any other suggestion

Comment: when you say "on the same page", do you mean on your site, because on facebook the URL has to be the whole "https://yoururl.extension/path/to/image.png", or it won't work. Could you maybe add a screenshot of the code or piece of code of the produced HTML file (so not the laravel file) to the question? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: yes, as I am using thumbnails and video title at many places in the same page so its working fine but what could be the problem in this case?

Comment: when I check the links using CTRL+U then it shows the correct links in meta tags.Don't know why it is not working

Comment: I just thought of something, are you testing this on a local website or on a public domain? Facebook has to be able to visit your site to generate the thumbnail.

Comment: I have used OG Tags and it works perfectly for twitter and facebook but there is no preview visible when I share it on whatsapp.

Comment: `<meta property="og:description" content="----">
<meta property="og:title" content="-----">
<meta property="og:url" content="----">
<meta property="og:image" content="-----">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="----" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="---" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="-----" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="720" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="720" />`